# Loops and counting in R

Tags: r, loops, count

I want to count how many times the numbers in the data set reaches a limt (let it be 8 and -8) after it returned to 0
in the attachment you can see a graph that explains my question better.
so with this set of data it should be 6 times. can you please tell me how can I code it in R, or which functions should I read in order to do it my self.

Data set:[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/88eVe.jpg)
{1
0
-8
-1
5
3
0
-9
-9
-8
0
7
-6
4
-4
5
-5
0
8
-6
8
-2
8
0
2
7
6
0
-8
-8
}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Some ideas:

```
a <- c(1,0,-8,-1,5,3,0,-9,-9,-8,0,7,-6,4,-4,5,-5,0,8,-6,8,-2,8,0, 2,7,6,0,-8,-8) 
b <- split(a,cumsum(a==0)) # b is of class list. The names of the elements names(b) are '1', '2', ...

found <- 0
for (i in 1:length(names(b))) { # iterate over all elements names(b)[i]
  if (sum(abs(b[[names(b)[i]]]) >= 8) > 0) { # i th part b[[names(b)[i]]]
    found <- found + 1 # if there is an entry >8 or <-8 increase counter
  }
}
```

Comment: `> a <- c(1,0,-8,-1,5,3,0,-9,-9,-8,0,7,-6,4,-4,5,-5,0,8,-6,8,-2,8,0,2,7,6,0,-8,-8)

> abs(a)
 [1] 1 0 8 1 5 3 0 9 9 8 0 7 6 4 4 5 5 0 8 6 8 2 8 0 2 7 6 0 8 8

> abs(a)>=8
 [1] FALSE FALSE  TRUE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE  TRUE  TRUE TRUE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE

[16] FALSE FALSE FALSE  TRUE FALSE  TRUE FALSE  TRUE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE  TRUE  TRUE

> a >= 8
 [1] FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE
[16] FALSE FALSE FALSE  TRUE FALSE  TRUE FALSE  TRUE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE
> sum(abs(a) >=8)
[1] 9`

Comment: so the result in this case is 9, but it should be less because in case where there is (0,-9,-9,-8) with previous code it counted it as 3 hits where it should counted as only 1 hit because the number didn't return to 0. ex: (0,-8,0,8,8) = two hits ...

Comment: @aRo See my edit. If this is not what you expect, please provide a reproducible example with all conditions and expected output.

Comment: I've tried it few times on different data and it seems to work well. Thanks!

Comment: @Christopher I've tried, but it says that I didn't unlock upvoting yet :/ . But I definitely going to upvot it when I will be able. Since I am still beginner, I am trying to understand the logic behind the code and I guess I have some difficulties to interpret the part from `if...` I would really  appreciate it if you explained it to me. :)

Comment: Don't worry: for voting you require at least 15 reputation. I forgot...